# Heroku scheduler added and rails console/rake tasks no longer work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, heroku-toolbelt

I have a deployed ruby on rails app that has been working perfectly.  I just added rake tasks to my app and added times for them to run using the heroku scheduler.  Everything works fine in my localhost environment.  Could it be ruby version related?

Today was the first day they were scheduled to run and this seemed to break some things.  Console doesn't work and I cannot manually run the tasks.  Here is my error:

```
Running `rails console` attached to terminal... /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/yajl-ruby-1.1.0/lib/yajl/yajl.bundle: [BUG] Segmentation fault ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [x86_64-darwin10.8.0]
```

There are several several more lines of error but perhaps this will be enough to diagnose my issue and propose a fix.

Comment: I have the same problem but when I run the heroku command line from outside of my application directory it works.

Comment: I'm having the same issue and I didn't do anything with scheduler. I just did a new deploy with a small change and all the sudden I get a set fault with yajl

Comment: Any idea why this happens or how to fix

Answer (score 0):

This issue fixed itself when I upgraded my OS to OS X.  Make sure you keep your operating system up to date.  I had to reinstall the heroku toolbelt once this was complete.